# Encrypted password in Net scp ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, scp

I'm using net scp to download a file from linux to linux/windos machine. I'm using the code as follows

```
require 'net/scp'
Net::SCP.download!(scp_host, username, filepath, targetpath, :ssh => { :password => password })
```

The problem here is I'm sending the password as a plaintext and this is a big security issue while dealing with production machines.

Is there any method in net scp to send encrypted password? Or else is there any other method to download a file securely using Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

While carrying the `scp` you have to provide the password. So you have to send it anyway.

What you can do instead is store the password in encrypted form and decode it right before scp. 
For eg. base64 encode the password while saving.

```
password  = Base64.encode64(params[:password])
```

While carrying your operation

```
Net::SCP.download!(scp_host, username, filepath, targetpath, :ssh => { :password => Base64.decode64(password) })
```

Base64 encoding/decoding is just an example. You can use any form of encryption depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is to use a ruby gem like [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline):

```
require 'highline/import'
require 'net/scp'
password = ask("Enter your password:  ") { |q| q.echo = false }
Net::SCP.download!(scp_host, username, filepath, targetpath, :ssh => { :password => password })
```